# Behat - Check list element contains content

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, behat, mink

I have a drop down menu containing list elements that are sometimes static and sometimes changed. My main goal is to check that the menu contains some content [followed by outputting that content and exporting it in a report].

The function I created in my FeatureContext.php looks like this:

```php
/**
 * @Then /^I check content exists for element "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iCheckElementContent($locator)
{

    //check element exists on page
    $element=$this->assertSession()->elementExists('css', $locator); 

    //check element content is not empty (returns exception if true)
    if ( empty($this->getPage()->find('css', $locator)->getText()) ) {
        throw new Exception;
    }
}
```

As you can notice, it is based on the reply to the other question regarding this feature. My problem however is that it doesn't seem to like the `getPage()` parameter. The error I get is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method FeatureContext::getPage()
```

I also tried changing it to getValue(), without any success. Any ideas? (bonus awesome points for also helping me with the second step of my requirements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution, but I'm not sure if it passes because it works or because it's searching for nothing and finding it.

```
    $session = $this->getSession();
    $element = $session->getPage()->find('css', $locator);

    //check element content is not empty (returns exception if true)
    if  (empty ($element->getText()) ) {
        throw new Exception;
    }
```

Can someone please code-review this?

Comment: Use $element !== null instead of empty. Also please note that find method will return null or object. If the element is not found and you will use a getText on null will result in a php fatal error. Check if the element is not null then use getText els throw exception.